# Unable to Upgrade Plugins in Craft CMS 4.8.0

Tags: craft4

In Craft CMS version 4.8.0, there is an issue preventing the successful upgrade of installed plugins using the command php craft update (plugin). Interestingly, when upgrading the plugin on an older version of Craft CMS, such as 4.7.1, the plugin upgrade functions as expected.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Open Terminal and log in.
2. Navigate to the respective project directory.
3. Upgrade Craft CMS to version 4.8.0.
4. Execute the plugin upgrade command using php craft update .
5. Verify the plugin version in the admin dashboard.

**Expected Behavior**

Executing the plugin update command should reflect the changes in the admin dashboard or project files.

**Actual Behavior**

Although the update command indicates that the update and migration processes are completed, the new version fails to impact the admin dashboard when checked. The expected changes are not reflected in the admin dashboard.

Comment: What plugins are you upgrading?

Comment: We're updating the ones below, but the issue is not related to any specific plugins. In Craft 4.8.0, we're unable to update any of the plugins in the update list. 

    - craft 4.7.1 => 4.8.0
    - feed-me 5.3.0 => 5.4.0
    - navigation 2.0.25 => 2.0.26
    - seomatic 4.0.38 => 4.0.42

Comment: What does Utilities > System Report say re. those versions? Do you see the expected (updated) version listed there? Is your site behind a caching proxy, like Cloudflare?

Comment: In the systems report it shows the older version, not the updated one as expected. Also, no Cloudflare is enabled on the site. I don't think this is related to the cache issue because we can update the plugins in previous versions like 4.7.1 or 4.7.2 and the updates are working as expected.